# PHP htmlspecialchars with MySQL - before or after storage?

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I have always been told to "sanitize" input to a database and one of the ways to do this (as well as using prepared statements) is using `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`.

This stores quotes as `&quot;` so printing the output of the database to a page "naked" has never been a problem for XSS attacks etc.

However, I have been asked to have part of my application export certain values as pure data in .csv format and now it's full of said HTML entities.

It seems that I have two options:

- Decode all values before exporting the data and leave everything else the way it is.
- Exclude "sanitation" before input to the database and make sure to sanitize on the output instead (except for data exports).

As much information as there is out there, I can't find the generally accepted way to do this - is it best to do this process on the way in or way out of the database? Obviously, doing both gives me silly values like `&amp;amp;`

Comment: html escaping has absolutely **NO** bearing on sanitizing for sql. you store your data in 'raw' format, and escape/escape/whatever for the specific purpose you're going to USE the data for. never store sanitized/escaped for a particular format, because odds are you'll just have to UNDO that escaping/sanitization for some other purpose. that means you use proper sql-injection-safe methods of inserting the data into the db, and then decide HOW to escape when you retrieve it later on, based on where the data's going.

Comment: to add to the comment above, you should use prepared/parameterized queries (PDO or Mysqli) to safe guard against sql injection. no escaping necessary on database input if you do so (and you should)

Comment: You should always prepare/encode/mask data specifically for the context you are putting it in. When you put it into the database, you prepare it for that – and only that. When you output it as HTML, you prepare it for that – and only that. Etc. pp. for all other possible situations.

Comment: Excellent comments. Completely understand you. The data quality should be the priority, with escaping depending on context. It involves more code rewriting to fix, but it'll be worth it.